# How would I got about calling a php file every time someone publishes a new post?

Tags: themes, functions, posts

I've got a custom php file that I want to call every time someone publishes a new post. How would I go about doing that? Can I write it into the functions.php of my theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action('publish_post', 'call_my_php_file');
function call_my_php_file($post_id){
  require_once("path/to/file.php");
}
```

Comment: so I can drop that into functions.php? nice!

Comment: I must not be doing something right as it doesn't appear to be firing....

Comment: if you're writing something to the screen, you won't see it because you get redirected after this action is executed. To see if your code works add a `die();` after require_once...

Comment: Ok i used your die command and it is running the script... now the problem is that I don't know where the xml is being generated that the script is making. the php that is.  It normally saves it to the folder it's in, but I don't see it.

Comment: ah ha! It's in the admin folder. so now I just need to figure out how to set the path for the save location. Thanks! This is awesome. From this I can make it so it updates on trash  and update post as well. I think...